# Plotting realtime .nmea files with QGIS 2.18.10

Tags: qgis, gps, tracking, nmea

I am working on a project that requires us to track 2 GPS targets, one car and one weather balloon. The realtime GPS tracking of the car via the COM port works great. The decoded data from our weather balloon however is poured into a growing .nmea file, is it possible to make QGIS (2.18.10) continuously update this imported vector layer in order to display this position realtime?

So far when we import the .nmea file, only the positions up to that point are shown and the vector layer isnt updated despite the sourcefile growing in size.